# How to fix my htaccess, it's redirecting my pages all to one index

Tags: html, .htaccess

I was on live chat with my domain support and they managed to delete the default htaccess file, now every url entered goes to my main index, what can I do to fix this?

Example:
domain: example.com

If I have a folder under example.com/folder
and go to it, the index for example.com shows instead of for that folder and if I put the path directly it stays in the browser but it shows the index for example.com always.

What can I write in my htaccess to fix this to how it used to be and keep mod rewrite enabled?

Edit: also, every time I've asked them to fix it or reset it to default they claim that it's a web development issue and not theirs. All they do is tell me to contact my developer.

Comment: Kindly post your current .htaccess file code.

Comment: There is none, as I said, the domain support also owns the hosting I'm using and they deleted it trying to fix a subdomain issue of mine. I'm asking how I can make an htaccess that would work how it originally did.

Comment: Only your domain hosting people can help you in this. Try to contact them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hopefully, it works

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: how will it work, can you add some explanation to your code?